# How to make stable +-5V from li-po battery?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am using LT3463 from Analog Devices to generate +-5V from li-po battery.
The ripple of DC/DC output is quite large. Then it affects back to the main power line.
Yellow is main power line (input of DC/DC)
Blue is output of DC/DC.
[image]

At the moment ripple happen at output, the main power line voltage drop.

For more information, here is my schematic.
[image]

I appreciate all your suggestions.

Thank you,
MinhDuc

Comment: How much ripple do you have? How much current are you drawing from each rail?

Comment: I got around 50mV ripple at +5V and 100mV ripple at -5V. 
I use 10mA load for testing at each rail.

Answer (score 1):

Some of this may be artifacts from noise on the ground or pickup from EMI.

How closely did you follow recommended layout [practices](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/scp-lt3463-evalz.pdf) from the datasheet and eval board?

[image]

If you need really clean DC you may need to add filters and LDOs on the outputs, but it really depends on your requirements, and that may not help that much if your layout is bad.

Comment: Hello Mr. Spehro Pefhany,

I locate the components quite similar to the IC chip as recommendation. 

Can you please explain more detail how it can pick up noise from GND and EMI?

Comment: It depends on where you put your probe ground, for example. If you put it directly across the input bypass capacitor you may see a different result than if it is a few cm away at a test point. Note how the eval board has SMA connectors for measurement purposes and recommends against long scope leads. Datasheet measurement show around 40mVp-p ripple on an 8V output.

Answer (score 0):

Part of being engineer requires reading datasheets as they are the best source of information if you have questions.

On page five of the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3463f.pdf), it mentions:

> *The formula below calculates the appropriate inductor value to be used for a boost regulator using the LT3463 (or at least provides a
> good starting point). This value provides a good tradeoff in inductor
> size and system performance. Pick a standard inductor close to this
> value. A larger value can be used to slightly increase the available
> output current, but limit it to around twice the value calculated
> below, **as too large of an inductance will increase the output voltage
> ripple without providing much additional output current.** A smaller
> value can be used (especially for systems with output voltages greater
> than 12V) to give a smaller physical size. Inductance can be
> calculated as:*
>
> [image]
>
> (formula found in the datasheet)
>
> *where VD = 0.5V (Schottky diode voltage), ILIM = 250mA (or 400mA) and tOFF = 300ns; for designs with varying VIN applications such as
> battery powered applications, use the minimum VIN value in the above
> equation. For most regulators with output voltages below 7V, a 4.7µH
> inductor is the best choice, even though the equation above might
> specify a smaller value.*

SW on your chip is typically a good culprit of noise when it comes to DC-DC switching devices. Decreasing your inductor values can mitigate that issue.

Comment: Hello Colin, I tried to decrease to 4.7uH but it does not improve too much. When you mention SW, is there any point we need to care when routing SW signal? Tks so much

Comment: @minkduchoangduc the SW node is quite possibly the single most layout-sensitive part of any switching converter; make sure it has very low parasitic capacitance (to any other node). Keeping it as small as possible and putting the inductor directly adjacent to the IC is usually recommended, as long as that's compatible with other layout requirements (such as keeping the overall current loops as small as possible).